# Не работает autocomplite

Tags: eclipse

Все сделал по [гайду](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912169/eclipse-enable-autocomplete-content-assist):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После точки ф-ции не подсказывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Замечу, однако, что при нажатии `ctrl + space` вылезает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы "дойти" до ф-ций нужно нажать `ctrl + space` еще несколько раз:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подозреваю, что дело в том, что оно предлагает то, что находится в списке, вызываемом с помощью одного тыка `ctrl + space`.

Comment: Eclipse в 2019? ლ(ಠ_ಠ ლ)

Comment: А мне кажется, он просто тормозит...

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Что же посоветуете со схожим функционалом?

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы после точки показывались подсказки, нужно в поле `Auto activation triggers for Java` нужно вписать `.` вместо `'XYZ._`.

В настройках `Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` можно отфильтровать и отсортировать нужные окошки с подсказками.

Comment: Мои догадки подтвердились - просто оставил галочку только у `Java Proposals (Task-Focused)` и все заработало. Оно тупо автоматом смотрело Default Proposals.